# How to get the login details of the user if the ID and Password matches with the data in the database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, login-script, login-control

In this form, the details(id and password) of the user are entered and it checks whether it matches with data present in the database, if it matches it allows the user to log in and it redirects the user to "action.php" page, else it shows the error message.
If the user logins successfully, I need to get the remaining details of the user according to the data in the database on "action.php" page.
As the database consists of first and last names, Email ID of the user.

```
This is login form:
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="main-wrapper">
                    <ul><li><a class="llink" href="home.php">Home</a></li></ul>
                    <div class="nav-login">
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="u_uid" placeholder="Username" />
                            <input type="password" name="u_pwd" placeholder="Password" />
                            <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
                        </form>
                        <a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

    <?php
    ob_start();
    include 'phpcode/dbh.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $db=mysqli_select_db($conn,'loginsystem');
        if(!$db){
            echo "DB  not found <br />".mysqli_error($conn); 
        }

        $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['u_uid']);
        $pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['u_pwd']);
        if(!$id==0 || !$pwd==0){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_uid='$id'";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $rescheck = mysqli_num_rows($res);
            if($rescheck<1){
                echo "<span class='error'>User-name and Password doesn't match</span><br />";
            }else{
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                    $dbid=$row['u_uid'];
                    $dbpwd=$row['u_pwd'];
                }
                if($id == $dbid && $pwd == $dbpwd){
                    session_start();
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['u_id'];
                        $_SESSION['user_fname'] = $row['u_fname'];
                        $_SESSION['user_lname'] = $row['u_lname'];
                        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row['u_email'];
                        $_SESSION['user_uid'] = $row['u_uid'];
                        echo "<div class='err-nav'><script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'action.php';</script></div>";
                        exit();
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='err-nav'><span class='error'>Password doesn't matched</span><br /></div>";

                    }
            }

        }else{
            echo "<div class='err-nav'><span class='error'>Cannot be empty</span><br /></div>";

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: As Your Question Title you can use `SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id = $userid`

Comment: Oh men... well, first of all: **NEVER NEVER NEVER** store passwords in plaintext in your database. Please use encryption and php functions such as `password_verifty()` etc. Also, escaping strings isn't enough, please use prepared statements (http://bobby-tables.com) to prevent SQL injection. Your code isn't safe at all and I would recommend you to fix that first before looking at your other problems.

Comment: @Twinfriends Yes you said correctly I will hash the passwords and de-hash it in my main project, but this is a sample one to test the functionality, thank you.

Comment: Thats just what everyone says. There are so many programmers here who are like "yeye don't worry I'll do that later" - **NO!** Why don't do it directly? You like to do the whole work twice? I don't get it. Anyway, may someone else will help you, but I definitly refuse to help on such code. I'm not ready to provide solutions on insecure code, sorry.

Comment: What issue you are getting?

Comment: @Twinfriends Thanks for your suggestions and contribution, I'll change the code.

Comment: @AmitGupta I need to get the remaining details of the user if he is authentic in another php page.

Comment: @K.MANIPRAJWAL `session_start()` has to be always on the top of each file. Before any include or output. Change that, put that line as well on top of your other files and simply access the session variables.

Comment: You can do it easily like you are doing in your login code. You can compare User Id or email you are storing in Sessions in another Select query in your action.php page.

Comment: I have tried but didn't get any required output. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $userid=$_POST['u_uid'];
    $password=$_POST['u_pwd'];
    $sql="SELECT userid,password where userid='$userid' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($database,$sql);
    if($result->num_rows>0)
    {
    header('location:action.php');
    }
    else
    {
    header('location:login.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need the hint to get details of the user in action.php file.

Comment: Hussian If I am using that header location then I am getting the error object not found! What should I need to do?

Comment: you check your file location its available or not,means file name correct given in header location

Comment: in action.php page you can ask more info.

Comment: Hussian I have tried but didn't get the required output.

Comment: what output you want after match?

Comment: Hussain, I need the Name and email details of the logged in user. Which is to be displayed on the top of the Welcome page.